# Rails Autoloading Nested Class: LoadError (Unable to autoload constant ModuleName::ClassName)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activesupport, ruby-on-rails-6

I use `app/services` to organize a collections of service classes. For example I have a light wrapper around NewRelic transactions listed in `app/services/metrics/transaction.rb`.

Rails autoloading has a tough time with this for some reason. I'll get constant loading errors like:

```
LoadError (Unable to autoload constant Metrics::Transaction, expected /Users/home/company/repo-name/app/services/metrics/transaction.rb to define it)
```

Of course the file (and 3 siblings to it) are defined in the listed location. This isn't an issue in production environments in which the constants are eager loaded.

The path is under `app` and I've checked the autoload paths so the file should be loaded, yet I have this problem whenever the constant gets hit for the first time.

Answer (score 3):

The key here seems to be that the constant is nested. It appears that the constant loader first attempts to load the module `Metrics` and failing to find that, issues an error.

If you create a file in `app/services` (or whatever your corresponding `app/*` autoloaded directory is) that defines the module constant:

```
# app/services/metrics.rb
module Metrics
end
```

then the autoloader will be able to cleanly load classes defined in `app/services/metrics/*`.

Comment: This requirement seems to be enforced as of Rails 5.2.0. Refer to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64601195/2769838) for more details.